# Save prompt answer as cookie

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a script to save a prompt's answer as a cookie, but instead of making a prompt, the name ID becomes a cookie called "cookie_date".

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  if (document.cookie === ""){
    document.cookie = prompt("Please enter your name", "")}
  const person = document.cookie
  if (!person) return; // empty string or null
  const text = person.toLowerCase() === "pyro" ? 
    "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!" : 
    `welcome, ${person}, to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage! <br> did you know you can drag the fake windows around?`;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;
})
```

- I wrote the script
- I expected it to show a prompt, accept the prompt answer and show text accordingly with prompt answer
- It printed a cookie called "cookie_date" instead of expected text

Comment: Is there any reason why you use cookies at all here? Wouldn't [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) be easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

In all the modern browser we have access to `localStorage` and this can help you to store information without using cookies with a lot better api.

This is the code snippet using `localStorage` which will achieve the same thing as your snippet.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('person')) {
    let personName = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
    localStorage.setItem('person', personName);
  }
  const person = localStorage.getItem('person');
  if (!person) return; // empty string or null
  const text =
    person.toLowerCase() === "pyro"
      ? "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!"
      : `welcome, ${person}, to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage! <br> did you know you can drag the fake windows around?`;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;
})
```

**Original Answer**

To save a cookie, the format should be `name=value`. `document.cookie` returns all the cookies as a string so for finding a specific cookie, you should use split and find.

Please refer this MDN doc for more examples and detailed explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Here is the updated snippet.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  if (document.cookie === "") {
    let personName = prompt("Please enter your name", "");
    document.cookie = `person=${personName}`;
  }
  const person = document.cookie
  .split("; ")
  .find((row) => row.startsWith("person="))
  ?.split("=")[1];
  if (!person) return; // empty string or null
  const text =
    person.toLowerCase() === "pyro"
      ? "hey, me! hope you've been making substantial changes!"
      : `welcome, ${person}, to the pyrogaming/covid2009 homepage! <br> did you know you can drag the fake windows around?`;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;
})
```